# How can I check if a DIV contains IMG tags with relative src paths?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm pulling a HTML page a server which contains various tags (img, div etc.).

On the client side, I'm inserting this into a div so that it is getting displayed exactly like the html file. It may contain images and text. But sometimes there are img tags whose src has a relative path.

How can I identify these img tags which don't reference a full http/https (absolute path) but rather start with "/" so as to identify that it is relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to check if the div contains `img`
- You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to grab the `src`

You can use string functions/regex to check if `src` attribute begins with `http`, `https` or `/` and change it accordingly.

Example:

```
$("#div1").find("img").length                  // returns the number of images inside #div1
$("#div1").find("img").each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");             // grab the src "attribute"
    console.log(src);
    console.log(src.indexOf("/") == 0);        // true -> starts with /
    console.log(src.indexOf("http://") == 0);  // true -> starts with http://
    console.log(src.indexOf("https://") == 0); // true -> starts with https://
});
```

Comment: Hey thnks.but I have 1 doubt.if the src is relative and appending it to some url.but how to display the Whole data again.Not getting :(

Comment: Image is not getting displayed which are having relative paths even if i append it to http.

Answer (score 2):

If the DIV you're using to display it has an identifier, then you can try to get the children of that div by using

```
$("#divID").children().find("img").each(function(){ 
    if(($(this).attr("src")).indexOf("PATH")>0) 
    { Do whatever.. } 
});
```