# Execute action after clicked two divs with same image in it - Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

I have another question for making a memory game. I'm at the point where the cards can be turned around, but now I want to check whether the clicked/flipped cards are the same or not. I was thinking to do this by comparing the src from the images inside the clicked divs, since they are the same for every pair.

I found something at an other question on this site, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404611/how-can-i-check-if-a-div-contains-img-tags-with-relative-src-paths). But how am I gonna get this done, to a clicked div, and then compare it with an other clicked div.

If anybody could help me a bit in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Let me know if you want some more information or something. Thanks.

EDIT: [See what I have right here](http://web-trend.nl/memory/).

Comment: hmm you would need to provide some code... anyways.. i would add a class to clicked image like `class="clicked"` and then compare the two elements with class clicked. and after two clicks you can remove that class?

Comment: Also i wouldnt compare sources, the easies way is to put your matching elements with the same class(you can use an index or something) and then compare classes.

Comment: @AminGharavi I'll setup an online fiddle or something like that quickly, I'll post the link asap. Thanks already.

Comment: @AminGharavi I've put something online, you can see it in the post.

Comment: Have a look at this [code](https://codepen.io/mel/pen/Brads)